# meaning of 1GE/5GE SFP in Cisco Switches

Tags: networking, switch, sfp

What is meaning of "1GE/5GE SFP Ports" in switches. What does it stand for? I dont have much knowledge of networking, but I just wanted for information.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

1 gigabit or 5 Gigabit Small form-factor pluggable transceiver ports.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_form-factor_pluggable_transceiver

Comment: In case somebody is wondering like me if there are some 5 Gbit fiber transceivers - answer is NO. These 5GE SFP are actually copper twinax cables having SFP on both ends with fixed lengths 1, 3 and 5 meters. Google for SFP-H10GB-CU1M